# In Meteor: How to use a npm library that should be pulled from a repository?

Tags: node.js, meteor, npm

In my packages.json file, I have:

```
{
    "sendwithus":"git+https://git@github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs.git#enable_testing_server"
}
```

because I need to use a forked ( and fixed version of the library). The above syntax works in straight node. How to do this in meteor?

This is the error I get:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Errors prevented startup:                  
While reading package from `src/packages/npm-container`:
package.js:14:7: must declare exact version of dependency:
   sendwithus@git+https://git@github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs.git#enable_testing_server
```

Update:

I tried removing the line and using meteor add to get the package included:

Failed:

```
meteor add sendwithus@2.9.1@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4

=> Errors while parsing arguments:           

While adding package sendwithus@2.9.1@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4:
error: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "@".
```

Failed:

```
$ meteor add sendwithus@2.9.1_https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4
 => Errors while parsing arguments:           

While adding package sendwithus@2.9.1_https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4:
error: Can't have two _ in version: 2.9.1_https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4
```

Failed:

```
$ meteor add server:sendwithus@2.9.1@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4
 => Errors while parsing arguments:           

While adding package server:sendwithus@2.9.1@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4:
error: Package names can only contain lowercase ASCII alphanumerics, dash, dot, or colon, not "@".
```

Failed:

```
$ meteor add sendwithus@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithusnodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4
=> Errors while parsing arguments:           

While adding package sendwithus@https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithusnodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4:
error: Version string must look like semver (eg '1.2.3'), not 'https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithusnodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4'.
```

Comment: are you using `meteorhacks:npm` package?

Comment: yes, I am. That is the code that is responsible for the error message. ( but it looks like the responsible code is in c not js )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer to this issue when I posted it to [enter link description here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4455), the only solution is to create a fake meteor package to wrap the new node library.

```
Npm.depends({sendwithus: "https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithusnodejs/commit/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4"});
```

To extend this answer:
Just to use a fork of a npm library requires:

1. packages/sendwithus/main.js:

   `SendWithUs = Npm.require('sendwithus');`

2.
packages/sendwithus/package.js:

```
Package.describe({
   summary: 'Wrapped sendwithus library',
   version: '2.9.1',
   name: 'sendwithus'
}); 
Npm.depends({sendwithus: "https://github.com/whalepath/sendwithus_nodejs/tarball/41b0d177f6eabf02de2daec9bb2b36daebbfbef4"});

Package.onUse(function(api){
   api.addFiles('main.js', 'server');
   api.export('SendWithUs');
});
```

3. removing the reference in the packages.json
4. meteor add sendwithus
5. Using the SendWithUs variable

Maybe this could be improved?